# SharePoint 2010: How can I pre-fill Scheduling Start and End Date?

Tags: date, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, scheduling, auto-populate

I would like to know how to pre-fill the Scheduling Start and End Date in the metadata/properties of each item edited or created in a SharePoint list.

Scheduling Start Date: *Today's date.*

Scheduling Start Date: *Today's date + one year.*

---

### [image]

---

**Reason for ask:** I configured the list items to expire and move into "draft" status when they hit their specified Scheduling End date, therefore un-publishing the item from external view.

**Problem:** Users/contributors are creating these items and are not entering enough time for it expire. What I'd like to do is automatically pre-fill the scheduling end dates for one year out from today's date when an item is edited or created.

**Background info:** I've enabled scheduling of items in a list (via "Enabling scheduling of items in this list" option in "Manage item scheduling" in Library Settings). I currently have a workflow and versioning enabled so that the admins check the content before it's view-able externally.

Your thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy using [Calculated Field Formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) in the default value fields of your two columns. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/peterbrunone/archive/2009/03/11/calculated-datetime-fields-in-sharepoint-lists.aspx) and [here](http://sridharu.blogspot.com/2009/01/set-default-date-time-to-datetime-field.html) are discussions on the basics of setting a default value for a date field, but it's pretty straightforward.

For Scheduling Start Date, set the default value to Today's Date. For Scheduling End Date, use the calculated value of `=DATE(YEAR(Today)+1,MONTH(Today),DAY(Today))` for the default value.

Comment: Thanks @AronFoster. I ran into a small issue: There is no calculated field within the "Scheduling Start/End Date" columns (see pic). FYI, these columns were created automatically after enabling "Manage item scheduling" in Library Settings (http://i.imgur.com/uxptLn5.jpg). I have a feeling it's due to the Column type (http://i.imgur.com/3bIwFmq.jpg)

Comment: If the workflow is the only thing tying you to the existing columns, I think it'd be easier to create new columns with default values and have the workflow reference those rather than trying to modify these columns. You might also consider using "Information management policy settings" to automatically trigger a workflow 1 year after items are created: then users won't even have to bother seeing the start and end dates.

Comment: Thanks Aron. This makes perfect sense. I just need to figure out how to get the "Manage item scheduling" feature to reference the new columns. You wouldn't know by any chance were to start? Since this scheduling feature is Out of Box SharePoint, I'm wondering if we can actually modify it's settings for referencing columns.

Comment: I'd recommend a different approach: rather than rely on "Manage item scheduling" to show and hide items, use a view filter that only shows items whose end dates are greater than [Today]. What other functionality are you looking to reproduce from "Manage item scheduling"?